# tableauSoftware.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE + is not working with different data source

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

We are trying to generate a report in tableau which will contain two filters.

Filter 1 (c_device_type): gets populate using: Select distinct(device_type) from fact_table

Filter 2 (region_name): select region from dimension_1

Please note, Filter 2 gets populated using different data source.

We are using Tableau java Script API's to set filters explicitly. Please see the code below:

```
activeSheet.applyFilterAsync(
"c_device_type",
"SMARTPHONE",
tableauSoftware.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);

activeSheet.applyFilterAsync(
"region_name", 
"Alaska",
tableauSoftware.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);
```

First snippet of code is able to apply filter (c_device_type) to filter SmartPhone's but the second filter (region_name) is not able to set filter and always returns with last selected value.

Can any one please point us if are we missing something silly ?

Thanks,

Hussain Bohra